# Get values from the form (OOP php)

Tags: php, oop

How I can get values $val1, $val2 from the form?

Probably need to use a design similar to this one:

```
$obj->Calculator($_POST['val1'], $_POST['val1']);
```

but .. where to paste?

```
<?php
class Calculator {
    private $_val1 , $_val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2){
        $this->_val1 = $val1;
        $this->_val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function add(){
        return $this->_val1 + $this->_val2;
    }

    public function subtract(){
        return $this->_val1 - $this->_val2;
    }

    public function multiply (){
        return $this->_val1 * $this->_val2;
    }

    public function divide () {
        return $this->_val1 / $this->_val2;
    }
}

$calc = new Calculator(3,4);
echo "<p>3 + 4 = ".$calc->add(). "</p>";
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
    Enter Number:
    <input type='text' name='val1' value="<?=$val1;?>">
    <input type='text' name='val2' value="<?=$val2;?>">
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Calculate'>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$calc = new Calculator($_POST['val1'], $_POST['val1']);`?

Comment: `new Calculator($_POST['val1'], $_POST['val1']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$val1 = (int) $_POST['val1'];
$val2 = (int) $_POST['val2'];

$calc = new Calculator($val1, $val2);
echo '<p>'.$val1.' + '.$val2.' = '.$calc->add().'</p>';
```

**Edit:** You can also type cast variables inside the constructor:

```
class Calculator {
    private $_val1 , $_val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2){
        $this->_val1 = (int) $val1;
        $this->_val2 = (int) $val2;
    }

    ...
}

$val1 = $_POST['val1'];
$val2 = $_POST['val2'];

$calc = new Calculator($val1, $val2);
echo '<p>'.$val1.' + '.$val2.' = '.$calc->add().'</p>';
```

Comment: It might be better to type cast the variables inside `Calculator` in the `__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use

```
is_numeric($val1);
```

to check if your inputs are numeric.

Read more
[php.net is_numeric](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)